# ModuleNotFoundError when I import module inside DAG folder

Tags: python, module, airflow

I installed airflow using the official helm chart. My dags are in a GitHub repository and have this structure:

```
dags
 |-directory
 |  |-test.py
 |-my_dag.py
```

When I try to import a test inside my dag, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test'`.

```py
from airflow import DAG
from directory import test

with DAG(...) as dag:

    ...
```

But strangely enough, if I do the import inside a function, I get no error and am able to use the module imported

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

def my_function():
    from directory import test
    *** Do something with test ***

with DAG(...) as dag:

    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task",
        python_callable=my_function
    )
    
    ...
```

I know this has to do with the path but I haven't been able to solve this issue.
Since my dags are located at /opt/airflow/dags/repo/dags, I tried adding

```py
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/airflow/dags/repo/dags')
```

at the top of my dag file but it doesn't help. I also tried adding this path to PYTHONPATH with no success.

Does anyone know where my mistake is?

Comment: Try the doc about [module management] (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html), you could place your code in `/airflow/plugins` folder, unless u have a specific reason to not to.

Comment: just before the import test, try defining `sys.path.append('/opt/airflow')` . let us know if that does not work. and also post the Dockerfile content.

Comment: Addind `sys.path.append('/opt/airflow')` didn't help. My dockerfile is very simple. I just added `ENV PYTHONPATH='/opt/airflow/dags/repo/dags'` to `apache/airflow:2.0.1-python3.8` image.
I'll try moving my code to `/airflow/plugins`. I'll let you know the result.

Comment: I tried using [community-maintained descendant of the stable/airflow helm chart](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/tree/main/charts/airflow) instead of official helm chart and now everything works as desired.
It is still a mystery to me that I could import modules inside PythonOperator but not outside.